# Normal Maps cause shading issues?

Tags: shaders, error, artifacts

I have a simple cylinder mesh with clean geometry. When I apply a Quixel material to it, the reflections seem jagged and wrong, as if the geometry is messed up.  Only happens with the normal map plugged in.  Activating "shade smooth" doesnt solve the  issue.   It's happens on other objects (suzanne monkey, human obj), and with other materials

Why are normal maps causing this?

[image: zigzagreflects]

[image: Cleangeo]

[image]

Comment: Try settings the color space to non-color for the Image Texture that is connected to the normal map.

Comment: @Tsybe that just lowered the contrast of the issue... and unforutnaly the contrast of the detail I want from the normal map

Comment: please pack the images and share the object so that we can test: https://pasteall.org/blend/